# Read Variable from Integrity, and get it with perl to sql

Tags: mysql, perl, mks-integrity

I'm using PTC Integrity at my firm. Here we have an Excel file which I need to transfer to our SQL Database with a Perl script.

In Integrity itself, there is a number for a Member Revision. I can see this Revision Number when I type:

```
echo %MKSSI_REVISION1%
```

in the command line. I tried to write this in Perl, but it's really hard for me. The Perl script should look for the Excel file Database.xlsx in the path `C:\Integrity_Sandbox\Database\Database.xlsx`, then read the Member Revision number, and write this number to my SQL Database.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can manage to do this?

Edit Solution:

```
my @result = `si revisioninfo --project=/Database/project.pj ´Database.xlsm`; 
my $integrity_version = @result[2];
chomp $integrity_version;
my @fields = split(/: /,$integrity_version);
$integrity_version = @fields[1];
 chomp $integrity_version;
```

Comment: Are the member numbers only in the Excel file, or can you fetch these with some MKS command-line utility?   Also, what did you try writing in Perl?  (Do you have to use Perl?)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i solved my Problem:

Comment: Can you post the answer?  Thanks!

Comment: I wrote it right in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bodaggnmo solved his problem with the following Perl code:

```
my @result = `si revisioninfo --project=/Database/project.pj ´Database.xlsm`; 
my $integrity_version = @result[2];
chomp $integrity_version;
my @fields = split(/: /,$integrity_version);
$integrity_version = @fields[1];
chomp $integrity_version;
```